# Unique constraint on two columns regardless of order

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [Car] 
(
   CarID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   FirstColorID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Colors(ColorID),
   SecondColorID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Colors(ColorID),

   UNIQUE(FirstColorID, SecondColorID)
)
```

I want the two Color columns to be unique, regardless of the combination they appear in.

E.g. attemping:

```
INSERT INTO Car (FirstColorID, SecondColorID) VALUES (1, 2); --should succeed
```

but then trying the same after that first record exists with the colors reversed should fail:

```
INSERT INTO Car (FirstColorID, SecondColorID) VALUES (2, 1); --should violate constraint/check
```

I have this problem solved using high-level code, but I'd rather the constraint be enforced directly in the database, preferably without involving things like triggers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe create computed column, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE [Car] 
(
   CarID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   FirstColorID int, --FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Colors(ColorID),
   SecondColorID int, --FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Colors(ColorID),
   xColor As Cast(Case When FirstColorID > SecondColorID Then FirstColorID Else SecondColorID End as varChar) + ',' + 
        Cast(Case When FirstColorID <= SecondColorID Then SecondColorID Else FirstColorID End as varChar),
   UNIQUE(xColor)
)
```

UPDATE (You should test it before, i did just very quick testing)

**Idea**:

Integer is 4 byts. If i put 2 integers together- i get 8 bytes. If i order them- i get unique BigInt value (8 bytes).

So what i do:

1. I make sure they are in correct order
2. I shift bytes of 32 bits to left (so just by multiplying 4294967296 i get what i want)
3. I make logical OR- so i get 8 byte BigInt value, that should always be unique!

So:

```
CREATE TABLE [Car] 
(
   CarID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   FirstColorID int, --FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Colors(ColorID),
   SecondColorID int, --FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Colors(ColorID),
   xColor As 
       Case When FirstColorID > SecondColorID Then 
            Cast(FirstColorID as BigInt) * Cast(4294967296 as BigInt) | Cast(SecondColorID as BigInt)
        Else 
            Cast(SecondColorID as BigInt) * Cast(4294967296 as BigInt) |  Cast(FirstColorID as BigInt)
        End
  UNIQUE(xColor)
)
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I'm not sure about using computed string columns on a performance basis. Maybe a numerical operation of some kind could be used instead? I guess it can't just be multiplying the numbers, there would be all kinds of collisions.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm going with. I like this approach because it's completely self-contained in the table definition and should be performant enough.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the problem entirely by putting in a constraint to require that `SecondColorID >= FirstColorID`.  It creates a limitation on what can go into the database that goes a bit beyond what you're looking for.  But that extra requirement will be useful down the line if you want to query for a certain color pattern, because you can just look for `SecondColorID = 1 AND FirstColorID = 2` rather than having to write extra logic to account for the two color IDs having an unpredictable ordering.

```
CREATE TABLE [Car] 
(
   CarID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   FirstColorID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Colors(ColorID),
   SecondColorID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Colors(ColorID),

   UNIQUE(FirstColorID, SecondColorID)
)

ALTER TABLE [Car] WITH CHECK
    ADD CHECK (SecondColorID >= FirstColorID);
```

Comment: That's a creative way to do it. But now I would need my high-level code to choose order the foreign keys just for an insert/update. It's better than what I had but still has the same basic problem.

Comment: A better option might be to take care of any parameter fudging in your stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

Create computed columns, so that ComputedFirstColorID  is the lower of FirstColorID  and SecondColorID, and ComputedSecondColorID  is the higher of FirstColorID  and SecondColorID. Now the index

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON Car (ComputedFirstColorID, ComputedSecondColorID)
```

Should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON Car (FirstColorID, SecondColorID)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Comment: That will prevent two entries of `(1,2)` - but when `(1,2)` is already in the table, this constraint **does not** stop `(2,1)` from being entered.....