# Unique constraint on two columns for any combination in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns 'Col_1' and 'Col_2' in the database. I want to apply a unique constraint so that Col_1-Col_2 and Col_2-Col_1 both combinations can be blocked.

Lets say, existing data combinations are:

```
Col_1    Col_2 
 ABC      DEF
 QWE      ZXC
 ASD      VBN
```

Now the following data insertion combination should not be allowed:

```
Col_1    Col_2 
 ABC      DEF
 DEF      ABC
 ZXC      QWE
```

Comment: So add a unique compound constraint on the table. I'm unclear on what the difficulty is, would you elaborate please?

Comment: [Unique constraint on two columns regardless of order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11414976/15498)

Comment: Unique Constraints on two columns check duplicates by the two columns' order. I want to block the duplicates of columns' reverse order as-well. Say if a row contains 'ABC' and 'DEF' in Col_1 and Col_2, then the insertion of ('ABC', 'DEF') and ('DEF', 'ABC') both need to be blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint may be created either when the table is created or by altering an existing table.

Create a new table

```
create table SomeTable(
  Col_1     varchar(20),
  Col_2     varchar(20),
  constraint unq_SomeTable_c1_c2 unique(Col_1, Col_2));
go
```

Alter an existing table

```
alter table SomeTable
add
  constraint unq_SomeTable_c1_c2 unique(Col_1, Col_2);
```

If duplicate insert is attempted the error message will be as follows

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 7502
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'unq_SomeTable_c1_c2'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SomeTable'. The duplicate key value is (ABC, DEF).
The statement has been terminated.
```

[EDIT] to ensure the order of the columns does not matter I created a `TRIGGER` which runs after `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.  The error message could be changed to whatever you wish.

```
create trigger trg_SomeTable_unq_c2c1_ins_upd on SomeTable
after insert, update
as
if exists(select 1 
            from SomeTable st join inserted i on st.Col_2=i.Col_1
                                            and st.Col_1=i.Col_2)
    rollback transaction;
go
```

Test Case

```
insert SomeTable(Col_1, Col_2) values
('ABC', 'DEF'),
('QER', 'ZXC'),
('ASD', 'VBN');

insert SomeTable(Col_1, Col_2) values
('DEF', 'ABC');
```

Output

```
    (3 row(s) affected)
    
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 7514
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Comment: that will block the combination of Col1-Col2 but not the combination of Col2-Col1.

Comment: After looking at various ways to accomplish the task, it seems a trigger would work best

Comment: Thanks @SteveC. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Issuing a rollback without throwing an error is not a good example of error handling nor trigger coding. How in the world is any code or person supposed to know that an error occurred and what that error was?

Comment: @SMor the question seemed focused on the constraint.  The OP could've (still could) follow up about the error handling.